# Socat - certificate rotation for mTLS connection - reload credential files interval

Tags: socat

*Use case:*
I use socat to stream traffic between some app and external world via Squid (app->socat->Squid). To authenticate in SQUID I use mTLS.

My socat usage:

```
socat -d -d tcp-listen:3128,reuseaddr,fork \
            openssl-connect:<SQUID_IP>:3128,cert=client-cert-key.pem,cafile-squid=squid-ca.crt,openssl-commonname=<SQUID_CN>-prd,keepalive
```

where
content of the PEM and CERT filles rotate.

*Problem:* If I put some trash into `squid-ca.crt` file socat after a couple of seconds catches the change and logs errors:

```
socat[72] E SSL_connect(): error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
socat[72] N exit(1)
socat[9] N childdied(): handling signal 17
```

, and when I recover `squid-ca.crt` file socat ater some time (several to several dozen seconds) fetches the change and starts working again with with the recovered data.

Is there an option to control the time on files probing by socat?

Answer (score 0):

Socat with your command waits for client connections and forks a new sub process for each one. Only in these sub processes the OpenSSL module is initialized and the certificate loaded.

So it is not some timing but just depends on the next TCP connection to arrive.

Comment: You are right. But at the same time new sub processes use a new file content after some kicks (a couple of them use the old version of the file).